# Sort a list according to the sublists

Tags: python, list, sublist

I am given a list:

```
lst = [[7090, 1.286], [7486, 2.569], [7571, 0.091]]
```

I want to sort this list in ascending order according to the second numbers of the sublists (namely, 1.286, 2.569, 0.091) so it looks like `[[7571, 0.091], [7090, 1.286], [7486, 2.569]]`. How should I do it by using python?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @Zee python. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Python lists build in sort function.

```
lst = [[7090, 1.286], [7486, 2.569], [7571, 0.091]]
```

A typical `.sort` call would sort it based on the first item per sublist, in ascending order.

```
lst.sort()
print(lst) # returns [[7090, 1.286], [7486, 2.569], [7571, 0.091]]
```

To sort it on the second item we can add the following:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda e: e[1])
print(lst) # returns [[7571, 0.091], [7090, 1.286], [7486, 2.569]]
```

The key passed to the `sort` function here takes in each sublist as parameter `e` and used the second element to sort.

Comment: @Amadan Oops. Thank you, was indeed using the wrong syntax. Corrected it now.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `key` parameter to `sort` (or `sorted`) to specify what you want to sort by.

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda item: item[1])
# => [[7571, 0.091], [7090, 1.286], [7486, 2.569]]
```

Alternately, you can use a predefined function from `operator` — this is equivalent:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1))
```